# RestLet Pagination

Tags: android, restlet, restlet-2.0

In iOS RestKit we have [RKPaginator](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKPaginator.html) to implement paging. Do we have anything of that sort in RestLet to implement paging logic?

Thanks.

Comment: Hang on, isn't that a client technology?  Won't it depend on the rest service?  Oh wait, just saw the android tag.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for Android Implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Restlet doesn't provide support for paging. It's a REST framework and you can leverage query parameters or headers to implement such feature. For more details, see the section "Filtering data" of this post: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/.

Hope it helps.
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's still helpful...

If you wanted to paginate a list of kid activities, your client executes a GET request to one of your end points.  Let's say '/feeds/kids/activities'.  The end point will return the following JSON document:

```
{
href: "http://localhost:8080/feeds/kids/activities",
offset: 0,
limit: 25,
sortBy: "createdAt",
sortOrder: "asc",
first: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/feeds/kids/activities?offset=0&limit=25&sortOrder=asc&sortBy=createdAt"
},
next: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/feeds/kids/activities?offset=25&limit=25&sortOrder=asc&sortBy=createdAt"
},
last: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/feeds/kids/activities?offset=47150&limit=25&sortOrder=asc&sortBy=createdAt"
},
items: [
{
_id: "55dc6064d6931a786b137acd",
name: "Coloring",
feedName: "kidActivity",
}
....
]
}
```

... if the next,last,first fields are defined, use the href property to callback for the subsecquent items.  You would use URL parameters to configure the database query on the backend.

[Lee Hazlewood did a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdSrT4yjS1g) that I found useful.